# QTP 11 and special (weird) keyboard inputs during Expert View coding

Tags: qtp

I am a pretty fast (>100WPM) typer and I am constantly hitting issues with QTP recognizing my input/keeping up.

Two examples that come immediately to mind:

- Shift+Space does not actually put in a space.
- Shift+BkSp undoes my backspace.

Is there ANY way to get QTP 11 to act like a regular program?  Shift+Space should still insert a space (just tried this while typing the question) and Shift+BkSp still deletes characters, like it should.

I'm constantly missing spaces during my test scripts (i.e. HELLOWORLD instead of HELLO WORLD) and I'm constantly having to redo my backspaces after a shift+BkSp entry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution to your problem.

You can change the Key Bindings with Tools>Options>Key Bindings. Unfortunately, you cannot use the Backspace as new shortcut key, because the interface thinks you want to delete the previous character (try it if you want, I wasn't able to do this in QTP 10). So we have to work around this:

1. Close QTP
2. Go to the `bin` folder of the QTP installation. In my case
   it was here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\QuickTest Professional\bin`
3. Open the QTEditor.ini file Change line `Delete before
   cursor=2097701` to `Delete before cursor=2097701,35652133`
4. Change
   line `Undo=35652095,35652133` to `Undo=35652095`
5. Save the file
6. Open QTP, you can now use `SHIFT + Backspace` to delete a character.

Unfortunately, you cannot enter a shortcut key for forward space.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll give this a shot.  I'm aware of the key bindings option inside QTP but I can never get the options to stick through a restart of the application.